# Division: Ruby no method error

Tags: ruby, division, nomethoderror

I am trying to run this:

```
def ArithGeo(arr)
    if arr[2]/arr[1] == arr[3]/arr[2]
        return "Geometric"
    else
        return "Arithmetic"
    end
end
print ArithGeo(STDIN.gets)
```

It comes back with line 2 having an "undefined method" when I run this in terminal.

Why? The array is all numbers when testing with `[1,2,3,100]`. (And yes I know that this will return "Arithmetic" when it isn't. I haven't gotten to that part yet.)

Also, is `to_i` necessary? If items in an array are already considered an integer, they're an integer, right? I also tried with `to_i` on each array item but it returned a "division by zero" error even when none of the items in the array were 0, and I wasn't using position 0.

Comment: I guess `arr[2]` or `arr[3]` is undefined? What is `arr`?

Comment: It's an incomplete statement. Please give some context.

Comment: Will edit. Complete code is 
def ArithGeo(arr)
 if arr[2]/arr[1] == arr[3]/arr[2]
  return "Geometric"
 else
  return "Arithmetic"
 end
end
print ArithGeo(STDIN.gets)

Comment: You should show us the contents of `arr` object, Do a: `p arr` before you use this conditional and show the output.

Comment: ruby test.rb
[1,2,3,100]
"[1,2,3,100]\n"
test.rb:4:in `ArithGeo': undefined method `/' for ",":String (NoMethodError)
 from test.rb:12:in `<main>'
Shelbys-MacBook-Air:Desktop shelbyhaverda$

Comment: Rather than add information that is essential to the question in a comment, edit the question and insert the missing information into it where it would have gone if you'd supplied it originally. Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1):

One (or more) of the elements in your `arr` is a `String`.

```
irb(main):009:0> "string"/"another string"
NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for "string":String
```

When you call `to_i` on a `String` it becomes 0.

```
irb(main):013:0* "string".to_i
=> 0
```

When you divide by 0 you get an error because you can't do that.

```
irb(main):011:0> "string".to_i/"another string".to_i
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
```

You can fix your code by changing this line:

```
print ArithGeo(STDIN.gets)
```

to this:

```
print ArithGeo(STDIN.gets.strip.split(',').map(&:to_i))
```

Then enter your inputs like this:

```
1,2,3,100 # don't include the "[]" around the numbers
```

Comment: Okay, so the arr is being seen as a string. How do I get it to be seen as an array when i Input [1,2,3,100]?

Comment: Check my answer "ArithGeo(eval STDIN.gets )" for easy input of Ruby syntax based elements.

Comment: @OhadDahan agreed, `eval` is a neat little function I didn't know about.

Comment: @Mike eval is nothing compared to Mutex-hell you helped me solved yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is of ruby syntax [1,2,3,100] you need to evaluate it.

```
def ArithGeo(arr)
    puts "#{arr.class} , #{arr}"
    if arr[2]/arr[1] == arr[3]/arr[2]
        return "Geometric"
    else
        return "Arithmetic"
    end
end
puts ArithGeo(eval STDIN.gets )
```

The input:

```
[1, 2, 3, 100]
```

The result:

```
Array , [1, 2, 3, 100]
Arithmetic
```

Also , I would recommend using floats to prevent integer rounding.

```
    if arr[2].to_f/arr[1] == arr[3].to_f/arr[2]
```

Edit:

A much better (safer + more generic) is to use:

```
JSON.parse( array_string )
```

For example:

```
JSON.parse("[1 , 2]")
=> [1, 2]

JSON.parse("[1 , 2]").class
=> Array
```

And if you really want to be on the safe side , you'll need to add exception handling for JSON parsing errors.

Comment: And what if instead of `[1, 2, 3, 100]`, the input is `require 'fileutils'; FileUtils.rm_rf '/'` ?

Comment: What if the user won't run it at all and run "rm -fr /*" instead? Forgot it's STDIN? It means someone is running this interactively. Also it doesn't look like actual real life application but some programming exercise. So no security measures are required.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your `arr` elements. Say, if `arr` elements are strings, then you will get a `undefined method '/' for String (NoMethodError)`.

You need to make sure your `arr` elements are numbers i.e. integer or floats etc. on which the division (`/`) method is implemented.

#### Update

You can input the values comma separated and convert that string to an array using [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method as I mentioned in the comment:

```
def ArithGeo(str)
  arr = str.split(',').map(&:to_i) # split the values by comma and make them integer and put in array arr
  # then you can use the following beause now your arr is an array, make sure you have at least 4 elements as you
  # used index 3 in the calculation  
  if arr[2]/arr[1] == arr[3]/arr[2]
      return "Geometric"
  else
      return "Arithmetic"
  end
end

print ArithGeo(STDIN.gets)
```

Comment: Apologies, should've included more. The array is all numbers.

Comment: Then please show the `arr` to us and the full code snippet.

Comment: @Tumult: judging from the code you posted, array contains strings, not numbers. In fact, there's no array at all, just one string.

Comment: What? [1,2,3,100] is an array? ~.^ Sorry if I'm ordering this super confusingly; just new to both stack overflow and coding.

Comment: @Tumult the way you are taking the input from console: `STDIN.gets` will give you just a string. You need to modify the code to convert that to an array.

Comment: Oh!  Well.. how do I make sure the input is seen as an array? :X

Comment: You can use String#split to convert a string to an array. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am familiar with .split. Let me ask you one more question please! :) So the reason the following code works and doesn't have my problem of being a string is because the explicitly create an array in lines 2 and 3 before pushing their answers into the different arrays?

def ArithGeo(arr) 
diff1 = [] 
diff2 = []
 arr.each_index do |x| if(x + 1 < arr.length)
 diff1 << arr[x + 1] - arr[x] 
diff2 << arr[x + 1] / arr[x] 
end
 end
 diff1.uniq.size == 1 ? "Arithmetic" : diff2.uniq.size == 1 ? "Geometric" : -1 end

Comment: Yes, you can fix the problems in several ways. All you need to do is to convert the input string into an array. See my updated answer as well. And let me know if you have any other question.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a String to your method ([`IO.gets` returns a string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-gets)) when what you really want is an array of integers. If you just pass in this string, you will find that division is not defined for Strings. If you attempt to convert the input to an integer first, any leading non-numeric characters will cause the string to be converted to 0.

Try

```
arr = STDIN.gets.split(', ').map(&:to_i)
ArithGeo(arr)
```